# How to use iRate library in my ios App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, irate

I am using iRate Files in my Application
But i am geting So many errors  like

1. Use of undeclared identifier '_messageTitle'
2. error This class requires automatic reference counting
3. Too many errors emitted, stopping now

   Please help me to overcome this situation if any using iRate Library
   Any Help acceptable........

Comment: If you get error messages, PLEASE take some time to research what they mean. For example, search for "This class requires automatic reference counting" would lead you to many answers including [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325394/having-errors-when-import-class-non-automatic-reference-counting-to-my-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this tutorial. It has the link to the project file too. Using that you would be able to use the properties.

Tutorial link is [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-adding-app-store-stars-with-irate/)

One more source Code with application is [Here.](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)

Hope it works.